# Receiving “(BotNotInConversationRoster) The bot is not part of the conversation roster for self created teams” channels

Tags: teams-toolkit

We have a MS Teams App and we are seeing that our message extension is not working in self created teams’ channels.

When trying to use any action of message extension in self created teams it is giving “(BotNotInConversationRoster) The bot is not part of the conversation roster.”

What are ways to handle this? Need to add any key in "manifest.json" file or have to use Graph API to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

The bot MUST be installed to the Team in order to get the roster for that Team. If the bot is not installed in the Team, you will get a "The bot is not part of the conversation roster" error.
You can connect the app by uploading your manifest to the Teams channel. Then you will get the roaster for that team.